# Change excel date format from slash to dot

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel file I have lot of data and there is one column with date formatted as 23/05/2015 as example. Now I want to change all the date as formatted like 23.05.2015. That is changing the date format from slash to dot.

As I said the file contains some thousands of rows. I don't want to go through all the rows and change it manually. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Select the column by clicking on the Letter at the top of the column.

Right-click and select "Format Cells"
Select the "Number" tab if it isn't already selected.

Select "Custom" under "Category".

In the box underneath "Type", enter `dd.mm.yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Public Sub example()
    Selection.Value = Replace(Selection.Value, "/", ".")
End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

Select the column, then do a find/replace of / with .